# How to dynamically resize a DIV when doing drag and drop operation?

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a container DIV where i can add other DIV and move them using drag and drop; if they are dropped outside, i show a scrollbar.
I would like, when a sub-div is dropped, to dynamically resize the container, so that the user does not see the scrollbar but the container is increased in size. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery resize plugin to resize the div on drop event.

Check resize plugin:
http://api.jquery.com/resize/